# getting the key/pair values out of an object that in an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Objects thats returned:

[image: Objects thats returned]

```
ref.orderByChild('name').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var results = snapshot.val();
```

When i log results the image is what i get, Ive been trying to access the value of 'active' for each of the three objects, phishing, information and techniques.

This is my first JS application sorry if its an easy one but couldn't find an answer else where that worked.

Comment: Could you make it clear exactly what question you are asking? Also it would help if you posted a complete code snippet. See [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There are two (common) ways to do this: the Firebase way and the regular JavaScript way.

#### the Firebase way

Since it seems you're returning a list of nodes, I'll start with the Firebase way.

```
ref.orderByChild('name').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var actives = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var result = childSnapshot.val();
        var key = result.key;
        var active = result.active;
        actives[key] = active;
    }
    console.log(actives);
}
```

So we're using Firebase's `Snapshot.forEach()` method here to loop over the child nodes.

#### the regular JavaScript way

Alternatively you can get the value of the entire snapshot as you already do and use plain old JavaScript to get the result you need. [Jatin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977225) shows one way to do that, but here's another:

```
ref.orderByChild('name').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    var results = snapshot.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(results); // ["information", "phishing", "techniques"]
    var actives = {};
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        actives[key] = results[key].active;
    });
    console.log(actives);
}
```

So in this case we're using `Object.keys()` to get the child node names and then loop over that array with JavaScript's `Array.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var snapshot = {
  "information" : {
    "active" : "y",
    "name" : "information"
  },
  "phishing" : {
    "active" : "z",
    "name" : "phishing"
  },
  "techniques" : {
    "active" : "x",
    "name" : "techniques"
  },
};

console.log(snapshot.information.active);
console.log(snapshot.phishing.active);
console.log(snapshot.techniques.active);
```